# matplotlib fill_between issue with x argument

Tags: matplotlib

I try to fill a space below my plot, the plot is y=x so it is a straight line with an angle of 45 deg. I try to fill the area below the curve from x=1 to x=10, how to do that using fill_between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what  [where](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) keyword argument is for.

> where :
>       If None, default to fill between everywhere. If not None, it is an N-length numpy boolean array and the fill will only happen over the
>   regions where where==True.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
>>> y = x**2
>>> ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x1e91250>]
>>> wh = (x>1) & (x<10)    
>>> ax.fill_between(x, y, where=wh, alpha=0.2)
<matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x24dd210>
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: in my case I used lists but that makes no difference. I got an error: raise ValueError("Argument dimensions are incompatible") x and y are the same dimmension, I can see the plot:/

Comment: @nykon Actually, using lists for the variable `x` makes a difference. When using `wh = (x>1) & (x<10)` where `x` is a `numpy.ndarray`, `wh` is assigned a `numpy.ndarray` of `bool`s. When `x` is a `list`, `wh` is assiged a single `bool`. As you can see in the answer provided by @Zhenya, `where` takes only `None` or a boolean `numpy.ndarray` as arguments; passing one `bool` as an argument gives a `ValueError`.

Comment: Yup, that's the point I did not think about this aspect. Thank You :)